# Does the python interpreter implicitly use the Chinese remainder theorem?

Tags: python, math

Steps to reproduce how I came to believe this:

```
>>> 2 ** 4324567
```

Keyboard interrupt the above if you get tired of waiting since the comparitive operation takes less than a second while the above takes like 20.

```
>>> 2 ** 4324567 % 55
```

You'll notice the one with the modulus operation is way quicker. The only way this could be possible is if it uses something like the Chinese remainder theorem right?

What's weird is that if the exponent (being what 2 is to the power of) is a calculated value (like `2 * 2162283` or `e` where `e = 2 * 2162283`) it doesn't do this it seems. Can someone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The time to do the exponentiation here:

```
>>> 2 ** 4324567
```

is actually brief, which you can verify by doing, e.g.,

```
>>> x = 2 ** 4324567
```

instead. The vast bulk of the time in the original is actually consumed by converting the internal 4-million+ bit binary integer into a decimal string for display.

That's expensive. Converting between base-2 and base-10 representations generally takes time quadratic in the number of bits (or digits).

Which is also why the one with the modulus operation appears quicker:  there are only 2 decimal digits to display. That goes fast.

However, if you're going to do modular exponentiation, use the 3-argument version of `pow()` instead. That can be unboundedly more efficient than computing a giant power first and only then doing a modulus operation.

Comment: "Converting between base-2 and base-10 representations generally takes time quadratic in the number of bits (or digits)." - it can be done faster with a more sophisticated base conversion algorithm, but Python's implementation goes for simplicity over performance.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about CPYthon - and doubtless every other implementation of Python. I didn't judge that the OP was likely interested in theoretical possibilities ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The Chinese Remainder Theorem is not used here, and not useful here either. If you want to do modular exponentiation, use 3-argument `pow`: `pow(2, 4324567, 55)`.

The second line runs much faster because almost all of the work in the first line is actually in constructing the string representation of the result, not in performing the exponentiation. The second line produces a much smaller number which is much quicker to stringify.

Comment: Nice! I was just about to post a partial answer with [`%timeit` results for not printing](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/448523a400a123c5d4c679e0c1f584ef), but this is more complete. Feel free to add in my results from the gist.

Comment: Take liberty to post ^^^ as some might not access to github: In [5]: %timeit 2 ** 4324567
17.8 ms ± 211 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit 2 ** 4324567 % 55
20.3 ms ± 74.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll probably use that pow call in future.